# wordtonumber function in node js issue

Tags: lambda

I executed the **npm install words-to-numbers** command via node js command prompt and uploaded the the lambda funciton zip file into the console and in the code mentioned the below import command. But i am getting the issue when i tested it from alexa skill console.

**import wordsToNumbers from 'words-to-numbers';**

or if you know any alternative solution please let me know the requirement is if you specify the word by speaking the number from alexa it should need to convert to number in lambda function.

Ex: alexa device is sending as **eight eight nine severn four** we need to convert as 8874.

Issue:

[image: isse screenshot]

Regards,
Raj.

Comment: why don't you use ```AMAZON.NUMBER``` slot? You can see more about the slot here (https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#number).

Comment: Thanks Sharan for your suggestion. You saved my lot of time and it did worked.

Comment: @sharankenam: Hi Sharan, Any idea on what slot type we can use it to pass a string message in alexa skill kit?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what user might say then create a custom slot type and insert the values which user might say and you can get more about custom slots [here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html#overview-of-custom-slot-types). And if you don't know what user might say then try using `AMAZON.SearchQuery` slot, you can get more info about searchQuery slot [here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#searchquery).

Comment: Thanks Sharan. I have used AMAZON.Person instead of AMAZON.SearchQuery because if i use search query and getting the error as ****Sample utterance "add {COMMENT} in {PROJECTKEY} {ISSUENUMBER}" in
  intent "AddCommentIssue" cannot include both a phrase slot and another
  intent slot. Error code: InvalidIntentSamplePhraseSlot*** hence used the other slot which i mentioned and it worked.